# not understanding what is going on here; anonymous function with jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry to ask a naive question but I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure a bunch of code into something that is easier to manage

I wanted to put events and their responses into 'controllers' for different sections of site. I was looking through the book [Javascript Web Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144930351X) and saw some promising stuff like this (p5 - my comment for what I thing I understand):

```
var controller={};  // ok- an object literal

(Controller.users = function($){  // creating an anonymous function; I don't get the dollar sign since it seems to work fine without it
  var jtClick= function(){
    alert('you clicked on me!');
  };

  $(function(){
    $('#view').on('click',jtClick);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

but I also noticed that this did the same thing:

```
var controller={};

(Controller.users = function(){
  var jtClick= function(){
    alert('you clicked on me!');
  };

  $(function(){
    $('#view').on('click',jtClick);
  });
})();
```

So do I need to pass jQuery as part of my anonymous function? Is this changing how scope is going to be handled? I updated the title to remove 'fully' since I don't think I'm getting much of this

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-invoking function and allows you to safely use jQuery with other libraries that use $ as a library object/variable.

$ in the above example is nothing but the jQuery object that is being passed while invoking the function.

Comment: thx, ok, if I'm only using jQuery, can I just leave it out? Can I make it something other than the $ so that it stands out a bit more? Sorry for dumb ?'s

Comment: That depends, are you planning on using another library like Mootools? Since Mootools also uses $ you would have to use `jQuery.noConflict()` and a function like the above.

Comment: hopefully not but could probably just add the declaration later if we did.

Comment: You could probably get a far better description than I could ever write here: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools P.S. If I answered your question, please hit the green checkbox on the left.